# Client-server in C and ethernet connection

Tags: c, client-server

I'm trying to develop a little client-server application in c. For that, I took a source code : http://www.iprelax.fr/outils/c_prog5.php

It's working in local without changing the ip address or the port. I tried with 2 computers (mac os and ubuntu). They are connected with an ethernet cable and we defined a static ip addresses 10.0.0.10 and 10.0.0.20 on this interface (eth0). In the client, we changed the line :

```
char *msg, *htoname = "127.0.0.1";
```

with the server ip address but it doesn't work, there is no error.

We tried to change the port number but still the same problem.

We saw anything with the netstat and netcat commands.

How to run the application between 2 computers ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to show more code! It's impossible to say as we don't know what you do.

Comment: Also, are you connecting the two computers directly or though a hub/switch? If you do it directly without any hub/switch between the computers you need a special network cable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Most modern network cards will probably have auto-sensing ports these days. Still, using a switch will make it certain, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When going between two machines, generally a firewall blocks incoming connections i.e. your server machine should allow client to connect to itself.

If your server is on Ubuntu, you are using Linux IP tables. Either add a rule to allow the server port for incoming connections or disable IP tables entirely.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5800 -j ACCEPT
```

The answer to this question list it in detail

[using ip tables on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804068/how-to-make-a-dhcp-server-listen-for-broadcast-requests-in-a-virtual-box-vm)

Comment: Thank you, we configured the firewall to accept connections by the other computer and it works fine :)

Comment: You are welcome. I myself faced this the first time i moved a socket client server from a single machine to multiple. So it was a suspected cause.